# Uniform inequalities, what are they?

Tags: analysis

I understand uniform convergence of functions, but what does it mean for an inequality to be satisfied uniformly?

This is a phrase from a peer-reviewed paper: "satisfying the bound $B(t) \leq K \exp(\vert{t}\vert / R)$ uniformly in every $S_τ$ with every $τ > σ$".

Why not write "satisfying the bound $B(t) \leq K_σ \exp(\vert{t}\vert / R)$ in every $S_τ$ with every $τ > σ$"? The subscript in $K_σ$ would imply that $K$ is a function of $σ$ but not of $τ$.